Reused async function for setting distinct state variables
I have an async function which fetches a DB object (Referral). In addition to the main fetch, other various parts of the application also fetch auxiliary Referrals through the same exact function and its logic.
An async function can't return anything so it can't be used as a generic return. Instead, we have to set a state variable with the results from it.
If I do
const [mainReferral, setMainReferral] = useState<Referral|null>(null);

// Fetch main referral
const fetchReferral = async (referralId:string) => {
    const response = await get<any>("/referral/" + referralId);
    // Lots of logic below, e.g.
    response['specialDerivedField1'] = ...;
    response['specialDerivedField2'] = ...;
    //...
    setMainReferral(response);
}

This only handles the single case of the main referral. I may also have
const [auxReferral1, setAuxReferral1] = useState<Referral|null>(null);
const [auxReferral2, setAuxReferral2] = useState<Referral|null>(null);
//...

Do I really have to add different params to this function to decide what to set with an if-else? This doesn't look very robust to me.
const fetchReferral = async (referralId:string, case1:boolean, case2:boolean) => {
   //... 
   if (case1) 
      setAuxReferral1(response);
   else if (case2) {
      setAuxReferral2(response);
   else {
      setMainReferral(response);
   }
}

Any other best practices for this? Or maybe pass in a string for the state var name, and then find the setter for it by name (not sure if React supports it)?
I'd also love to just isolate this utility function in a separate utility file that doesn't deal with state, but as an async function that would be impossible, I'm guessing?

is passing the setter function an option? I mean, instead of the booleans...

Yes. Would that be considered the best practice for this kind of situation?

ALso, just to confirm, there is no way to isolate this is a non-state-related utility function due to its async nature?

Dependency Injection of a success callback (the function executed upon successful data query) is the way to go, as being pointed out in the very first comment. And this way, your fetchReferral() can be isolated.

If you want to get fancy, you could also add a useReferral custom hook which handles the state variable for you. In such way you can isolate the fetch function and the state inside the custom hook.

"An async function can't return anything" - Says who?  Anything it returns is simply wrapped in a Promise to be resolved.  "ALso, just to confirm, there is no way to isolate this is a non-state-related utility function due to its async nature?" - Is that the goal?  The function can return a Promise which resolves to a value, and the component can invoke this function and update state with the resolved value.  Is that what you're looking to do?  There are different approaches to take here.

Yeah I was looking for the best and most common approach. Do people actually resolve promises in this scenario of a shared utility fucntion?

@geneb.: "Best" is subjective.  It's entirely reasonable and common to have async utility functions, and for components to invoke those functions and use their resolved values in state.  It's also reasonable to pass a callback function to an asynchronous operation, and that callback function can certainly be a state setter.  If the question is which of these two approaches any given member of this community personally prefers, such opinion-based questions are off-topic.  Either approach is technically correct.  Have you tried one and encountered a problem?


An async function can't return anything

Whoever told you that has misinformed you.  Or you may have misunderstood what was being communicated.
Your async function can indeed return a result:
const fetchReferral = async (referralId:string) => {
  // existing code, then...
  return response;
}

And any given component can update state with that result:
// using await:
const referral = await fetchReferral(someValue);
setMainReferral(referral);

// or using .then():
fetchReferral(someValue).then(setMainReferral);


Alternatively, if you prefer to encapsulate handling the Promise in the function itself, you can pass the state setter(s) as a callback.  For example:
const fetchReferral = async (referralId:string, callback:(x:any)=>{}) => {
  // existing code, then...
  callback(response);
}

And any given component would pass a function as the callback:
fetchReferral(someValue, setAuxReferral1);


Another option could be to wrap the operation and state within a custom hook.  For example:
const useReferral = function () => {
  const [referral, setReferral] = useState();

  const fetchReferral = async (referralId:string) => {
    // existing code, then...
    setReferral(response);
  }

  return {
    referral, fetchReferral
  };
};

And any given component would simply use that hook:
const { referral, fetchReferral } = useReferral();

// somewhere in your component logic:
fetchReferral(someValue);

// and use "referral" as the state value


Thanks, good summary I went with #2, the callback argument; my type is :Function. The Hook example is also good.
